# The expansion of $\tan^{-1}x$ for the end points about convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Determine the convergence of interval for the function $\tan^{-1}x$ . I know this question is very classical and standard and **I am not very sure of the part for the end points** .

For $x\in(-1,1)~$ , one has $$\tan^{-1}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}~.$$

**Determine the end points $x=\pm 1$** ,

$(i)~$ for $x=1$ , the summation turns into $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}$ , then this is an alternating series since each tern $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n+1}$  decreases and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}=0$ .

$(ii)$ for $x=-1$ , it becomes $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}(-1)^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n+1}$ , thus , this series converges by alternating series test since for the similar reasons that  each term $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n+1}$ is decreasing and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n+1}=0$

Can someone check my proof for validity if you have the time . Any comment or advice I will be grateful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.

I know you see the denominator goes to infinity, but it's more clear and useful to do it like so when dealing with more tedious coefficients

$$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\frac{1}{n}}{n\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{2+\frac{1}{n}}=0$$

It would also be better to get in the practice of proving that the sequence decreases for the same reasons like this

$\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}\sim f(x)=\frac{1}{2x+1}$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{-2}{(2x+1)^2}<0\space\forall\space x\in\mathbb{R^+}$$

$$\therefore a_n\space\text{decreases for all n}$$

This is typical but certainly not always the case